# Gamma fuction of odd numbers divided by 2

Tags: gamma-function

Defining the gamma function in the usual way,
\begin{align}
\Gamma(u)=\int^{\infty}_{0}t^{u-1}e^{-t}dt
\end{align}
We know that for the positive integers we get $(u-1)!$ and the property $\Gamma(u+1)= u\Gamma(u)$. I'am trying to prove that when $u = \frac{n}{2}$ where n is an odd integer positive number, we get the following expression:

\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(\frac{n-1}{2})!}
\end{align}

I'd like suggestions as I'm not making any progress by myself, please.

Comment: There's a proof of this using induction on proofwiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gamma_Function_of_Positive_Half-Integer

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$, try the substitution $t=s^2$ in the integral.

Once you have $n=1$, you can get the others via the functional equation.